# kotlin-multiplatform timestamp to time in milliseconds (unix time)

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

I'm using kotlin-multiplatform for iOS and Android targets.

I'm deserializing json string with timestamp inside: 2020-01-16T11:33:34.553Z

I would like to convert this timestamp to time in milliseconds (unix time). Is it possible to do this using kotlin native libraries?

I'm using kotlin multiplatform 1.3.72.

Comment: There is are several libraries to deal with Date and Time in Koltin/Multiplatform. I would recommend you to start with [this list](https://github.com/AAkira/Kotlin-Multiplatform-Libraries#date-time) and find the most applicable for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it with native kotlin libs like this:

```
timeValue.toInstant().epochSeconds
```

where `toInstant()` is a function in the `kotlinx.datetime` library.